# Scale elements of a structure using a cast

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I got this question/assignment on a test yesterday at university. It goes like this:

```
Give the following structure:

typedef struct _rect {
     int width;
     int height;
} rect;

How could you scale the width and height members using a cast to int* without explicitly accessing the two members?
```

So basically, given that struct, how could I do

```
rect *my_rectangle = malloc(sizeof(rect));
my_rectangle->width = 4;
my_rectangle->height = 6;

// Change this part
my_rectangle->width /= 2;
my_rectangle->height /= 2;
```

Using a cast to int or int*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can scale reliably only the *first* member:

```
*((int *) my_rectangle) /= 2;
```

This does not violate *strict aliasing rule*, as the Standard explicitely allows to convert pointer to struct object to the pointer of its first member.

> #### C11 §6.7.2.1/15 Structure and union specifiers
>
> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in
>   which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in
>   which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably
>   converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.
>   There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
>   beginning.

Assuming that, there is no padding between those members, the second member may be scaled as well, as long as the pointer is of the same (compatible) type as of the member, that is `int`.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this. Basically, their solution would be to pretend there was no padding at all and access each sizeof(int) bit from the structure?

Comment: @Xzenon: I checked the rules again and the second case does not violate strict aliasing as long, as the pointer is of type `int`. So, if there is no padding, then, it should be fine to scale the second member as well. The only issue is with portability, because other compiler may use some padding.

Answer (score 1):

What they're trying to teach you is how that struct is represented in memory. It has two int members, so it's possible that within memory it could also be viewed as if it were an array of int. So the following could possibly work.

```
rect *my_rectangle = malloc(sizeof(rect));
my_rectangle->width = 4;
my_rectangle->height = 6;

int *my_array=(int *) my_rectangle;
my_array[0] /= 2;
my_array[1] /= 2;
```

But it's a really dirty hack and it's entirely possible that a compiler could store your struct in an entirely different way, such that casting it to an `int *` would not have the desired effect. So not at all recommended if you want to write good clean portable code IMHO.

And if someone were to change the struct, such as by making width & height be `float` instead of `int`, the code would probably compile without any issues or warnings and then not work at all how you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

you have starting address of structure, so you can access individual elements
by incrementing address correspondingly. Here since both types are int you can use integer pointer else better to use char pointer.

```
int *ptr = my_rectangle;
*(ptr) /= 2;
*(ptr+1) /=2;
```

Comment: However, you need some means to ensure that there are no padding present in between the integers. And also `int *ptr = my_rectangle` is not valid C, since you cannot implicitly convert from a `_rect*` to `int*`, they are not compatible types.

Answer (score 0):

This task is rather questionable since you can easily end up with invoking poorly defined behavior.

As it happens, we can get away with it since the types of the struct are `int`, same as the pointer type, and there is an exception in the strict aliasing rule for this.

There's still the issue of padding though, so we would have to ensure that there's no padding present between the integers.

The obscure result is something like this:

```
// BAD. Don't write code like this!
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct 
{
  int width;
  int height;
} rect;

int main (void) 
{
  rect my_rectangle;
  my_rectangle.width = 4;
  my_rectangle.height = 6;

  int* ptr = (int*)&my_rectangle;
  *ptr /= 2;

  _Static_assert(offsetof(rect, height) == sizeof(int), "Padding detected.");
  ptr++;
  *ptr /= 2;

  printf("%d %d", my_rectangle.width, my_rectangle.height);

  return 0;
}
```

---

It is much better practice to use a `union` instead. We would still have the same padding issue, but wouldn't have to worry about strict aliasing. And the code turns easier to read:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union
{
  struct
  {
    int width;
    int height;
  };
  int array[2];
} rect;

int main (void) 
{
  rect my_rectangle;
  my_rectangle.width = 4;
  my_rectangle.height = 6;

  _Static_assert(offsetof(rect, height) == sizeof(int), "Padding detected.");

  my_rectangle.array[0] /= 2;
  my_rectangle.array[1] /= 2;

  printf("%d %d", my_rectangle.width, my_rectangle.height);

  return 0;
}
```